# Transform array of Strings into Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops

Given the following values:

```
const values = ['name1|engine1|color1', 'name2|engine2|color2', 'name3|engine3|color3']
```

I would like to create an array for the values ​​of the same position, like this:

```
cars = {
  names: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
  engines: ['engine1', 'engine2', 'engine3'],
  colors: ['color1', 'color2', 'color3'],
  ...other properties
}
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
values.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const [name, engine, color] = value.split('|')

  acc.names.push(name)
  acc.engines.push(engine)
  acc.colors.push(color)

  return acc
}, {})
```

The problem is that acc.name, acc.engine and acc.color don't exist yet, and it gives an error on push. What would be a way to do this cleanly, taking into account that they will have other properties?

Comment: Can't you set proper initial value for the reduce? Instead of empty object `{}`, use `{ names: [], engines: [], colors: []}` instead

Comment: Set them in advance as @zzz recommended if you know them but you can set them conditionally if they don't exist using [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) `(acc.names ??= []).push(name)`. This is most useful when the keys aren't known in advance or are derived from the reduced elements.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 3):

- **Case1.**

```js
const values = [
  "name1|engine1|color1",
  "name2|engine2|color2",
  "name3|engine3|color3"
];

const cars = {
  names: [],
  engines: [],
  colors: []
};

const result = values.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const [name, engine, color] = value.split("|");

  acc.names.push(name);
  acc.engines.push(engine);
  acc.colors.push(color);

  return acc;
}, cars);

console.log(result);
```

- **Case2.**

```js
const values = [
  "name1|engine1|color1",
  "name2|engine2|color2",
  "name3|engine3|color3"
];

const result = values.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const [name, engine, color] = value.split("|");

  (acc.names ??= []).push(name);
  (acc.engines ??= []).push(engine);
  (acc.colors ??= []).push(color);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very long property names, you can also do this:

```
const values = [
  "name1|engine1|color1",
  "name2|engine2|color2",
  "name3|engine3|color3"
];

const keys = ["names", "engines", "colors", ...];

const results = values.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const segments = value.split("|");
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    (acc[key] ??= []).push(segments[index]);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) makes this easy to do this in a simple `map` call:

```js
const reconstruct = (names, values) =>
  values .map (v => Object .fromEntries (v .split ('|') .map ((v, i) => ([names[i], v]))))

console .log (reconstruct (
  ['name', 'engine', 'color'], [
  'name1|engine1|color1', 
  'name2|engine2|color2', 
  'name3|engine3|color3'
]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We convert each of our strings into something like `[['name', 'name1'], ['engine', 'engine1'], ['color', 'color1']]` then call `Object.fromEntries` on that.